# Stack Overflow is very slow (again)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, performance

For the last two days or so, loading random pages from SO and MSO may take up to a minute (the time to load the page content, not counting the linked resources).

A typical experience is

[image]

Other notable offenders are static files such as css and js.

Don't have any speed problems with other websites.

Comment: No repro (FF 69.0.3 on Win10 x64)

Comment: Might be a regional CDN or other network issue. I just emptied my cache and everything is still snappy in Southeast Asia.

Comment: @BoltClock You're probably right; for me it's coming from `fastly-ic-336129-hls-b2.c.telia.net` and `hls-b2-link.telia.net` if that's of any help.

Comment: ... and now it's super snappy again, after two very sad days, right after I posted the addresses. Did you do something @BoltClock? I will keep an eye on it, but it looks like it's fixed.

Comment: I showed up, that's what. (I had vanished again for the last 15 days.)

Comment: Can reproduce since today (Russia, Windows 7 with Firefox 69.0.3).

Comment: Was definitely noticeably slow for me earlier this week (UK), but seems ok at present.  I'd assumed the current dramas had provoked a DDOS.

Comment: Slow again right now, static assets seem to be the problem.

Comment: I had trouble scrolling a few minutes ago. A few weeks ago nothing loaded on Main.

Comment: I had the same thing. It was consistent the other day. Am getting some loads very slow today.

Comment: Sorry all, my activity has been sporadic and that might be the cause of all your issues. I shall leave a browser tab on the site 24/7 until the problem self-corrects. Apologies once again for the inconvenience. (This is tongue-in-cheek, in case it was too convincing.)

Comment: Aaaand it's slow again in .uk at around 17:35 GMT.

Comment: Slow again lately

Comment: I keep facing this issue, how come it's still unsolved!